# Remove dropdown list value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following select drop-down which is dynamically created,which does not have select id but have name.
I have JavaScript array like
var t=[125,43,89].
I want to remove above array values from below drop-down.

```
<select name="UF_DEPT">
<option value="">no</option>
<option value="125"> . Volkswagen</option>
<option value="43" selected=""> . . AMC / INS / EW</option>
<option value="66"> . . CPU</option>
<option value="89"> . . New York Office</option>
<option value="107"> . . Paris Office</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A form cannot have multiple select with same name, So when you set name for select, set id with same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var t = [125, 43, 89];

t.forEach(function(item) {
  $("select[name='UF_DEPT'] option[value='" + item + "']").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="UF_DEPT">
<option value="">no</option>
<option value="125"> . Volkswagen</option>
<option value="43" selected=""> . . AMC / INS / EW</option>
<option value="66"> . . CPU</option>
<option value="89"> . . New York Office</option>
<option value="107"> . . Paris Office</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the array and delete the `<option>` elements with the corresponding value (using the `option[value='...']` jQuery selector):

```
var t = [125, 43, 89];

t.forEach(function(item) {
  $("select[name='UF_DEPT'] option[value='" + item + "']").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var child=$("select [name='UF-DEPT']").children();
foreach(child as sub-child){
if($.inArray(sub-child.val(),array){
subchild.remove();
}
}
```